# ArCore Fragment navigation optimisation with addImage() and session

Tags: android, arcore

I have build application using `ArFragment` from `com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.9.0`. I have added navigation which recreates displayed fragments. But creating `ArFragment` lasts a very long time.

Firstly I saw that method `addImage()` takes most of the time. In documentation one can find that:

> Note: this method takes about 10-20ms for a 5MB byte input stream. Run
>   this in a background thread if this affects your application.

But when I moved:

```
augmentedImageDatabase.addImage(DEFAULT_IMAGE_NAME, augmentedImageBitmap)
```

to anther thread to run it asynchronously ArCore stoped recognize nor detect this marker.

Then I thought that maybe I should store `AugmentedImageDatabase` and reuse it. But such database constructor uses `session` so I guess that database has to be recreated every time.
I ended up with resizing image to speed up things.

After profiling I found out that second slow thing is creating session. Is there a possibility to reuse session? I found out that saving it from `BaseArFragment` is impossible because all methods for creating session are private.

Should I implement `BaseArFragment` on my own for better performance or should I always keep instance of ArFragment in Fragment Back Stack and only cover It with other views? How I can add images in runtime if `addImage()` in background thread doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with rewriting BaseArFragment from `com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux` to start session with loading images in background thread. Camera view starts now about 1 sec later but UI thread is not blocked. I also resized image, used as marker, to be less than 1k px in width and height, whick made loading faster. I belive that image could be even smaller, as docs says:

> - The image's resolution should be at least 300 x 300 pixels.
> - Using images with high resolution does not improve performance.

In future I will consider keeping fragment in back stack, but changing marker will still require to reload the whole session.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem since I am trying to add 6 images by using a loop which takes a time blocking the UI thread.

Tried to do it in background thread by using coroutines but the camera it does not recognise the images in this case. 

Is there any specific way to solve this problem by rewriting BaseArFragment?